# Android AlertDialog prob

Tags: android, background, android-alertdialog

I have created AlertDialog with custom layout. I have fallowed the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) of 'Creating a Custom Layout' for this purpose. The AlertDialog is working fine. But my requirement is when the Dialog is active, the buttons background will not work. But in few devices, the buttons of remain active. What may be the problem?

Comment: I have resolved it by using the following code:
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

Answer (score 0):

If this only occurs on few devices, there might be some device-specific issues. You may check if the dialog is currently active and get the problem solved quickly. Pseudo-code:

```
 public void disableButtons(boolean dialogShown)
  if(dialogShown)
    yourButton1.setEnabled(false);
    yourButton2.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I have resolved by the following code:
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by using the following code:
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);